# Quickly Focusing on Dialog Buttons Other Than Those in Focus

Tags: keyboard, finder

In macOS dialog menus, two buttons are usually already in focus: one will probably be encircled in blue and is invoked by hitting <kbd>Space</kbd>, the other will be filled in blue and can be invoked by pressing ↵.

Sometimes, there's only one button in focus (like in the following image) or there are simply more buttons than the two already in (either kind of) focus.

[image: figure1]

**In either of those cases, is there any way to quickly set focus on the unfocused buttons?**

P. S. - I was considering settings this:
[image: figure2]
To `All controls`, but that's too much of compromise in dialogs where I actually need quickly to move between boxes and modify their contents.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a set of default keyboard shortcuts that should serve the need of interacting with the default file save sheets:

- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to **Save**.
- Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to **Cancel**.
- Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key combination to **Delete** or Delete Copy, Don't Save, etc.

Comment: @Nimesh Thanks for your edit, but in my opinion enabling Full Keyboard Access is **not** the preferred approach, as this means you have to spend time tabbing between the buttons and manually interacting with them. I much prefer the shortcuts to directly press the buttons. Feel free to leave an answer yourself regarding your opinion on Full Keyboard Access, however I will be editing this back out of my answer since it doesn't represent my view, thanks

Comment: I don't see how `All controls` cannot be the preferred navigation method. Take a look at the [default macOS printing dialog](https://i.imgur.com/Rgac1n4.png), for example. With `All controls` turned off, you can't set focus to checkboxes (among many others) like `Black & White` or `Two-Sided` in order to quickly tick or untick them with **Space**.

Comment: @voronoi It's not the preferred option for interacting with the Cancel/Save buttons, but *is* the preferred option if you wish to regularly interact with the rest of the sheet with the keyboard. It's personal preference, and personally I do have All controls enabled, but when it comes to this specific question regarding pressing the Don't Save/Cancel/Save buttons with the keyboard, enabling All controls is excessive.

Comment: I see, thanks. What could be done for dialogs with options other than the default "Don't Save/Cancel/Save"? For example, [Photoshop has "Discard" button](https://i.imgur.com/ytETWFh.png), which isn't invoked by `CMD+⌫`.

Comment: @voronoi Does ⌘D work for Don't Save? Esc should cancel and Enter would Save. ⌘D is the old shortcut macOS used to use before ⌘⌫, and it's possible that Photoshop has programmed that dialog manually, since it doesn't look like the standard macOS document-based dialog.